# adding several elements via foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

i am trying to parse an array of double numbers instead of static string like i did here to test, i will enter number in textbox and after clicking button it will pick all relevant coordinates from database. so i need to parse many pairs of coordinates (lat,lon) i tried foreach loop but couldn't figure out at 3rd last line. name of field in databse are Longitude and latitude.

```
new XElement(n + "Linestring", new XElement(n + "Coordinates", lat+","+lon))))));
```

code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //String[] values = {"12.1", "2.1","3.1","2.1" };
        String values = "12.1,2.1,3.1,1.1";
        String[] latLon = values.Split(',');

        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        // String com = "select Latitude, Longitude from Coordinates where IMEI=@txtIMEI";
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("GetLatLon", sqlcon);
        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
        sda.Fill(dt);

        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();


                double lon = double.Parse(latLon[0]);
                double lat = double.Parse(latLon[1]);
                Response.Write(lon + "," + lat);

                XNamespace n = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2";
                Response.Write("KML Generated");
                new XElement(n + "kml");//just do n+ for each underlying elements
                //  XNamespace n = "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2";
                XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
                new XComment("This is comment by me"),
                new XElement(n + "kml",
                new XElement(n + "Document",
                        new XElement(n + "Name", "something"), new XElement(n + "Placemark",
                        new XAttribute("id", "1"),
                        new XElement(n + "title", "something"),
                        new XElement(n + "description", "something"),
                        new XElement(n + "LookAt",
                        new XElement(n + "Longitude", "12.1"),
                        new XElement(n + "Latitude", "2.1")),
                        new XElement(n + "Linestring", new XElement(n + "Coordinates", lat+","+lon))))));
                        doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\marker5.kml"));
                        Response.Write("KML Generated");



        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Response.Write(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: You should explain what the actual problem you are having is if you want any useful answers. Is it throwing an error (if so, is it compile-time or run-time)? I also don't see a foreach loop in the code posted so it's unclear what you're actually trying.

Comment: Btw. decimal is better than double for storing latitude/longitude.